# How to create standalone installer from pip package?

Tags: python, pip

I am installing a pip package called SSLyze on CentOS offline like this

```
pip download SSLyze  # this downloads all the other pip dependencies as well in the same dir
pip install --no-index --find-links ./ SSLyze
```

The problem with this approach is I need to install `gcc` and a bunch of other packages for this to work. And also install time is long as gcc needs to compile the SSLyze source.

**I would like to create a binary installer like `SSLyze.run` which will install everything offline. Is there any python tool to do so?**

I have previously tried to created RPM from the SSLyze pip package and it ends up being a dependency nightmare; I ended up having to repackage lots of python packages from pip as the ones in CentOS official repo are too old to make SSLyze run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

**On build host**: install the required packages for building

```
yum install epel-release
yum install gcc  python2-pip python2-devel openssl-devel 
pip install wheel cryptography
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

**On the build host**: build the wheel files for SSLyze and all its dependencies

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=./sslyze_setup SSLyze==1.1.1
```

This will create all the `*.whl` files in `sslyze_setup/` for offline installation

**On the target host**: copy all the files from build host inside `sslyze_setup/` to the target host

```
yum install epel-release
yum install python2-pip
pip install --no-index --find-links=./sslyze_setup SSLyze
```

(Afterwards, rpm or deb file can be created from the files in `sslyze_setup/`)

Answer (score 3):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) generate binary installers.

`pip wheel -r requirements.txt` builds separate wheels for all requirements. The wheels can be moved to the offline host and installed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about the wheels files.